# Caret in Direct2D text editor

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, direct2d

I am making a graphics application in Direct2D, and it has text editing capabilities powered by DirectWrite. However, I am not sure what the best way to render the caret is. I can either get the position using `HitTestTextPosition` and render a line manually, which seems to work, or I can attempt to use `SetCaretPosition` and related methods. The Direct2D surface does not cover my entire window.

What are the pros and cons of each approach; and which one would provide better usability/robustness?

Comment: What is your language: `c#` or `c++`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev c#

Comment: Where did you get `SetCaretPosition` from? I can't find it in TextLayout.